# How to make Gboard (Google Keyboard) look like the 4.4 version?

Tags: gboard

With the advent of Android 5.0, Google has switched to a new design (Material) for their keyboard.

Can one install a theme (or change a setting) to make it look like the classic version again (or close to it)?

Answer (score 0):

> Still looking for an answer.

There is a way to do this, but it doesn't necessarily solve the problem.

http://www.howtogeek.com/253941/how-to-change-google-keyboards-theme-on-android/

which makes the keyboard look like this:

[image: New keyboard look]

However, the keyboard still doesn't look much like 4.4's keyboard:

[image: 4.4 look]

Comment: Yes it does, unless you're using an outdated Gboard or the AOSP keyboard.

Comment: Mark, Just Nab the AOSP keyboard.